# Is Java DatagramSocket class thread-safe?

Tags: java, networking, thread-safety

If multiple threads write to the same socket, will be the data possibly corrupted? (e.g., a packet sent to incorrect recipient).

```java
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) datagramSocket.send(<DATAGRAM_PACKET_RECIPIENT_A>);
}).start();
while (true) datagramSocket.send(<DATAGRAM_PACKET_RECIPIENT_B>);
```

Comment: Data corruption is not possible, and nor is sending to the wrong recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatagramSocket#send` is synchronized on the data packet you send, so yes.

Comment: Any link pointing to the specific source code? Thanks

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.java.html However note that this obviously depends on the implemetation you are using. So check for JDK and/or frameworks.

Comment: You can also check the open JDK repo, if you check for `DatagramSocket` you end up here via `delegate`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/059ede0d2054abe27be220643cccf8a56c4edea8/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/NetMulticastSocket.java#L322